# Gulp: paths.scss.forEach is not a function

Tags: foreach, gulp, gulp-watch, watchify

I have written the following gulp task:

```
var paths = require('./package.json').paths;

var watching = false;

gulp.task('scss', function () {
    var processors = [
        autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 0.5%', 'ie >= 8', 'ie_mob >= 10', 'ff >= 30', 'chrome >= 34', 'ios >= 7', 'android >= 4']
        }),
        cssnano({
            autoprefixer: false,
            safe: true
        })
    ];
    var streams = merge();
    var development = (gutil.env.type === 'dev10');
    paths.scss.forEach(function (path) {
        streams.add(gulp.src(path.scss.src + '**/*.scss')
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass())
            .pipe(postcss(processors))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dest)));
    });
    return streams;
});
const watch = gulp.parallel('js', 'scss');

exports.watch = watch;
```

Where `js` is another task, that is running without any error. Currently I am stuck at making this `scss` task work, as I am constantly receiving an error saying `paths.scss.forEach is not a function`. I have written the following in my `package.json` file that is placed in the same directory as of my `gulpfile.js`:

```
"paths": {
    "js": {
      "src": "../client/js/",
      "dest": "../static/default/js/"
    },
    "scss": {
      "src": "../client/scss/",
      "dest": "../static/default/css/"
    }
}
```

I am having the following `traceback` in the CMD:

```
[16:38:08] Starting 'watch'...
[16:38:08] Starting 'js'...
[16:38:08] Starting 'scss'...
[16:38:08] 'scss' errored after 84 ms
[16:38:08] TypeError: paths.scss.forEach is not a function
    at D:\XYZ\gulpfile.js:92:13
    at taskWrapper (D:\XYZ\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:293:12)
    at asyncRunner (D:\XYZ\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
[16:38:08] 'watch' errored after 91 ms
[16:38:08] The following tasks did not complete: js
[16:38:08] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

What should I do in this case, as I am stuck at the moment, without any ideas on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `paths.scss` is an object.  `forEach` is a property of an array.  So use a `for in` loop instead.

```
gulp.task('scss', function () {

  // paths.scss.forEach(function (path) {

  for (var path in paths.scss) {

    console.log(path);  // src, dest

      streams.add(gulp.src(path + '**/*.scss')

      // streams.add(gulp.src(path.scss.src + '**/*.scss')
      //     .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      //     .pipe(sass())
      //     .pipe(postcss(processors))
      //     .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
      //     .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dest)));
  };
  // return streams;
});
```

But you only want `path.scss.src` anyway - you don't want to run your `sass` loop over `paths.scss.dest` - which is what you are trying to do.  Get rid of the for loop altogether:

```
gulp.src(paths.scss.src + '**/*.scss')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(postcss(processors))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scss.dest)));
```

Comment: so will this work even if I have a 100 `.scss` files in that path?

Comment: Yes, each will be run through that task unless it is a partial scss file.

Comment: I also need this task to keep running, even if the js and scss tasks are done with, so that when I make any change in those files, it should automatically go through this watch task, in this case also, will this code work?